# Require that all cheboxes are selected

Tags: jquery, checkbox

So I have a field with checkboxes that need to be selected before being submitted.
The problem is that it is not a constant number of checkboxes because it depends on the number of values fetched from a database that are to be checked against.

Basically, the number of checkboxes range from 1 to 9.

I am sending the values using ajax so i have not listed the 'checkbale items' in a form, rather, they are in a list. Something like this

```
Unit 1: <input type="checkbox" name="unit[]" value="1"/>
Unit 2: <input type="checkbox" name="unit[]" value="2"/>
Unit 3: <input type="checkbox" name="unit[]" value="3"/>
Unit 4: <input type="checkbox" name="unit[]" value="4"/>

<input type="submit" value="register units"/>
```

Question is: How do I ensure that every time,all the checkboxes will be checked before submiting.

Answer (score 4):

like this:

```
if($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == $('input[type="checkbox"]').length){
  //all checkboxes are checked.
}
```

You can also use name attribute to target elements using `$('input[name="unit[]"]'` and `$('input[name="unit[]"]:checked')`

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it in this way-

```
     <form name="myForm" action="targetpage.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">  
         Unit 1: <input type="checkbox" name="unit" value="1" />  
         Unit 2: <input type="checkbox" name="unit" value="2" />  
         Unit 3: <input type="checkbox" name="unit" value="3" />  
         Unit 4: <input type="checkbox" name="unit" value="4" />  
         <input type="submit" value="submit" id="XISubmit" />  
     </form>  



 <script>  
     function validateForm() {  
         if (validateCheckbox(document.forms["myForm"]["unit"])) {  
             alert('All good!');  
             return false;  
         }  
         else {  
             alert('Please select all checkboxes.');  
             return false;  
         }  
     }  

     function validateCheckbox(chk) {  
         for (i = 0; i < chk.length; ++i) {  
             if (!chk[i].checked) return false;  
         }  
         return true;  
     }  
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
if($('form input:checked').length == $('form input:checkbox').length){
//submit
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! How did i not think about this? :(

Answer (score 0):

in the submit handler, check the length of the unchecked checkboxes if it is more than 0 then show the errror message and prevent the default action

```
if($('input[name="unit[]"]').not(':checked').length){
    alert();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but will this go through all the checkboxes listed at any given point in time irregardless of the number of said checkboxes?

Comment: I do not really understand how this works, would you mind briefly explaining what this last part  '.not(':checked').length)' does?

Comment: @JohnKariuki I hope you are clear about the first part `$('input[name="unit[]"]')`... if so `.not(':checked')` will filter that set by selecting only the unchecked checkboxes... so now we have a set of unchecked checkboxes... `.length` will return the number of items in the set.. something like `0`, 1, 2 etc... if all are checked then it will return 0 else a +ve int value which are considered as truthy value so it will satisfy the if condition

Comment: Thank you!! Such brilliance is admirable!

Comment: @JohnKariuki still can't figure out why it was downvoted

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="unit[]" value="1"/>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unit[]" value="2"/>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unit[]" value="3"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="unit[]" value="4"/>
 <input type="button" id="buttonsubmit" />
```

Here is your html

Here is jquery

```
$('#buttonsubmit').click(function(){
$('.checkme').each(function(){
  var aa="all"
  if(!$(this).is(':checked'))
  {
  aa='notchecked';

  }

  if(aa=='notchecked')
                   {

                   alert('all not checked');
                   }
                   else

                     {
                       alert('all checked');

                     }

});
});
```

Checkout this demo [Click here](http://jsbin.com/vohayubi/1/edit)